# Autosar memory protection

Tags: autosar

I'm confused about autosar memory protection mechanism

I have two applications, one trusted one non trusted

I configured a memory protection region range from `0x70000000 to 0x7100000` for the trusted application, and I configured an init task for the trusted application

In `init task`, if I try to directly write to the memory address inside the configured range it works fine.

If however, I try to write outside the configured range (still correct memory address) I go into an exception

If it happened to a non trusted application I can understand but this is a trusted one

I thought the trusted application can write to whole memory?, what I'm missing here

Answer (score 2):

AUTOSAR_SWS_OS (R19-11) has a Configuration-parameter called `OsTrustedApplicationWithProtection`

> Parameter to specify if a trusted OS-Application is executed with memory protection or not. `true`: OS-Application runs within a protected environment. This means that write access is limited. `false`: OS-Application has full write access (default)

Sounds a bit like, your trusted OSApplication is configured here like with `true` instead of `false` and therefore also write restricted.

On the other side, ch. 14 "Outlook on Memory Protection Configuration" it states:

> As stated before, memory protection configuration is not standardized yet. Nevertheless it seems helpful to contribute a recommendation in this chapter, how the configuration might work

Ch. 14.1 also gives hints, how the MPU config should be handled (SWCD/BSWMD specifying the (CODE/VAR/CONST/..) memory sections and linker-input-sections), so you should not just use arbitrary memory definitions and accessing it directly, but using the AUTOSAR memory mapping way.

And what I do not understand in your case, why do you actually restrict the trusted application by giving the MPU config just this range, instead of restricting your non-trusted application's access?